# cakephp complex db query with associated tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

im trying to retrieve some data using a cakephp methods but i'm not sure if i can do it using only one query.

i have the tables mentioned below

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

    CREATE TABLE dates (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date_id int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (date_id) REFERENCES dates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders_products (
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    qty INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id,order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

and i want to retrieve the sum of the qty ( quantity ) of each product, from all orders that was made on a specific date.

I know how to make the query in plain sql but i dont know how to make it using cakephp methods.

`SELECT products.id,count(op.qty) as quantity FROM orders INNER JOIN orders_products as op on op.order_id=orders.id INNER JOIN products on op.product_id= products.id WHERE orders.date_id = '1' GROUP BY products.id;`

The image shows what the sql query gives me.

[image: results]

But i can't get the same results using cakephp methods.

What i have tried:

```
$query= $this->Orders->find();
$data = $query
     ->select([
       'quantity' => $query->func()->count('qty'),
       'pid'=> 'Products.id',
    ])
    ->innerJoinWith('Products')
    ->where(['date_id'=>2])->groupBy('pid');
```

result :

```
object(Cake\\Collection\\Collection) id:0 {
'count' =\> (int) 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i managed to find a solution i think, i dont know if it's the best way to do it but it works.. if you know a different way pls write it.

The main problem was that i used ->groupBy instead of ->group

```
        $query= $this->Orders->find();
        $data = $query
        ->select([
            'sum' => $query->func()->count('qty'),
            'pid'=> 'Products.id',
            ])
        ->select($this->Orders->Products)
        ->innerJoinWith('Products')
        ->where(['date_id'=>1])->group('pid')->all();
```

Comment: Using `group()` is the correct way, `groupBy()` is a result set collection method, [**calling it on a query**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects) will execute the query first, and then apply the method on the results. In newer versions calling proxied result set methods on query objects is deprecated, and throws a warning accordingly. It will be removed in 5.x completely, where you then have to call `all()` first to obtain a result set on which you can then invoke collection methods.